# I want to duplicate an object accross scenes but without deuplicating the materials attached to it

Tags: materials

Right now my Duplicate Data options under the Blender Preferences are set NOT to duplicate data material but this only work accross the same scene, not for the whole Blender file. Is there a way to only duplicate the mesh but not the materials? Because I'm using the same few shaders for all my scenes and it's important I don"t get any duplicate for batch rendering.

Comment: Don't think material should be duplicated. By which mean are you duplicating the object?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out copying a whole collection will duplicate materials, this won't happen if you select materials and copy them from the viewport context. Learned something new!